# AVfoundation save photo to custom album iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, avfoundation

I have created a custom camera with `AVfoundation` framework (objective C) and I am saving photos using

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

But it just saves to default camera album. I want to save my photos in a custom album, but `ALAssetsLibrary` or ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.h is not working with `iOS8` any more. I have tried every thing but nothing works in `iOS8`.

So the following does not work :

```
[self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"CustomAlbum" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
```

Could you please help me save photo to custom album in `iOS8`?

Thank you a lot.

The following methods does not work inside ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum ,in `iOS8`, class:

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock
{
    //write the image data to the assets library (camera roll)
    [self writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)image.imageOrientation 
                        completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {

                          //error handling
                          if (error!=nil) {
                              completionBlock(error);
                              return;
                          }

                          //add the asset to the custom photo album
                          [self addAssetURL: assetURL 
                                    toAlbum:albumName 
                        withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];

                      }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested some of my old code I had for creating photo albums and this still works.  I have made some helper methods for you so you did not have to piece together blocks of code. Hope this helps learn what you did differently.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface AppDelegate()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

static NSString * const customPhotoAlbumName = @"CustomAlbumv2";

- (void) setupPhotoAlbumNamed: (NSString*) photoAlbumName withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(ALAssetsLibrary*, ALAssetsGroup*))completion
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    __weak ALAssetsLibrary *weakAssetsLibrary = assetsLibrary;
    [assetsLibrary addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:photoAlbumName resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@ Album result: %@", self, (group.editable ? @"success" : @"already existed"));
         if (!group)
         {
             [weakAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *g, BOOL *stop) {
                 if ([[g valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:customPhotoAlbumName])
                 {
                     completion(weakAssetsLibrary, g);
                 }
             } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
                 completion(weakAssetsLibrary, nil);
             }];
         }
         else
         {
             completion(weakAssetsLibrary, group);
         }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
        completion(weakAssetsLibrary, nil);
    }];
}

- (void) addImage: (UIImage*) image toAssetsLibrary: (ALAssetsLibrary*) assetsLibrary withGroup: (ALAssetsGroup*) group
{
    [assetsLibrary writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) metadata:nil
                                    completionBlock:
     ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
         }
         else
         {
             [assetsLibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
              {
                  [group addAsset:asset];
                  NSLog(@"%@ Image was succesfully added!", self);
              } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
              }];
         }
     }];
}

#pragma mark - UIApplicationDelegate

- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*) launchOptions
{
    UIImage *imageToAddToAlbum = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
    [self setupPhotoAlbumNamed:customPhotoAlbumName withCompletionHandler:
     ^(ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary, ALAssetsGroup *group) {
        if (group)
        {
            [self addImage:imageToAddToAlbum toAssetsLibrary:assetsLibrary withGroup:group];
        }
    }];
    return YES;
}
@end
```